# alternative for setsc comand

Tags: opensolaris, solaris-10

I have solaris machine ( from uname -a 5.10 Generic_142900-15 sun4v sparc SUNW,Netra-T2000 )

the command (setsc sc_powerondelay true) should be performed only from sc prompt

my question what is the alternative for setsc command 
because I want to set the (sc_powerondelay to true)  only from Solaris !!! ( and not from sc prompt )

please advice which tool can help me and how to get it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the scadm command.

However, scadm was not included in early versions of Solaris 10 for the T2000. See the T2000 [product notes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19596-01/819-5840-16/index.html).

Comment: so the only one tool is the scadm ? no other option ?

Comment: scadm is used from Solaris. It is an alternative to using the sc prompt.